# Odata sort by min value from array

Tags: request, odata

I have `odata` query:

```
/url/odata/ContractCards?
$top=20&
$count=true&
$filter=ContractId%20eq%2013ff820e-1ac7-ea11-a97d-899ae03249bd&
$orderby=LicenseType/Name%20asc&
$select=Id,ContractId,CardNumber,Name&
$expand=
    Contract($select=ContractTypeCode,ContractVersionSetId),
    ContractCardRightAssignments
                ($orderby=Right/Name%20asc;
                $select=Id,ContractCardId,StartDate,EndDate,IsEstimatedStartDate,
                    IsEstimatedEndDate,IsInPerpetuity,RightId,Note,RunCount,RunCountNote,
                    IsRunCountUnlimited,HoldBackLength;
                $expand=Right($select=Id,Name,TypeCode),
                    HoldbackType($select=Id,Name),
                    HoldbackFromRightGroup($select=Id,Name),
    ...
                )
```

The result of the query is sorted by `LicenseType.Name` list of contractCards:

```json
{
    value:[
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard1",
        ContractCardRightAssignments:[{RightName:"Right1",StartDate:"2020-01-01"},{RightName:"Right2",StartDate:"2019-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"A license"}
    },
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard2",
        ContractCardRightAssignments:[{RightName:"Right3",StartDate:"2019-01-01"},{RightName:"Right4",StartDate:"2018-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"B license"}
    },
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard3",
        ContractCardRightAssignments:[{RightName:"Right3",StartDate:"2018-01-01"},{RightName:"Right4",StartDate:"2017-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"C license"}
    }
]
}
```

I want to change sorting, to get the result sorted by `min(StartDate)` value, so the result should looks like(2017,2018,2019):

```json
{
    value:[
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard3",
        Rights:[{RightName:"Right3",StartDate:"2018-01-01"},{RightName:"Right4",StartDate:"2017-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"C license"}
    },
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard2",
        Rights:[{RightName:"Right3",StartDate:"2019-01-01"},{RightName:"Right4",StartDate:"2018-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"B license"}
    },
    {
        ContractCardName:"ContractCard1",
        Rights:[{RightName:"Right1",StartDate:"2020-01-01"},{RightName:"Right2",StartDate:"2019-01-01"}],
        LicenseType:{Name:"A license"}
    }
]
}
```

I tried to change the query in part

```
$orderby=LicenseType/Name%20asc&
```

to something like

```
$orderby=ContractCardRightAssignments/StartDate.Min()%20asc
```

but no luck.

How to change the query to order the reault in a such way?

Comment: can you provide the class definition of contract and right?

Comment: after a lot of search I found that OData V4 does not support orderby collection specific value, you need to order inside your code